# How to pass password in Jenkins shell script in safe manner?

Tags: shell, maven, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I have below shell script in my jenkins job which execute after successful build.

*sshpass -p 'mypassword' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  myusername@myhostname "cd /opt/temp/test/ && ./stop-services.sh"*

This script is useful to goto specifc directory in target server and run .sh file . This is working fine. My only problem is that the password is visible in jenkins logs (console output) after every build.

Can anyone help me if there is any other way to avoid this password visibility in logs or any-other way to pass it to the script.

Thanks & Regards,
Somi J.

Comment: The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) for `sshpass` says, "The -p option should be considered the least secure of all of sshpass's options ... people writing programs that are meant to communicate the password programatically are encouraged to use an anonymous pipe and pass the pipe's reading end to sshpass using the -d option". The [website here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/) gives directions on how to create and use an encrypted file containing the password

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has a credentials store which can be used by [pipelines via](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/)

```
node {
  withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'mylogin', variable: 'USERPASS')]) {
    sh ( 'curl -u "$USERPASS" https://private.server/ > output' )
  }
}
```

which is the safest way...

Comment: But my job is not a pipeline, it's Maven project. is there any other way for maven project

Comment: There is a plugin call credentials provider plugin in Jenkins but I would recommend to go to pipelines there are more flexible have other advantages...